# Can I play all WoW content with just the Battle chest?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just got the World of Warcraft Battle chest last year, and I just got to play it. So I  installed it.  It took me to battle.net, I made an account, and clicked some starter edition option. I logged in and played, no problem.  My question is: am I playing the battle chest, and do I have everything including the Burning Crusade and Wrath of the Lich King?

Comment: Remember, if one of the suggested answers helped you or were the answer you were looking for, you can select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

The World of Warcraft battle chest includes all of the expansions up to and including Wrath of the Lich King, however, a starter edition subscription only allows you to level up to level 20. In order to progress past this point you will need a subscription.

The battle chest will let you level up to level 80 with a subscription, and play all of the content up to Wrath of the Lich King. Of you want to continue levelling past this point you will also need both the Cataclysm and Mists of Pandaria expansions.

Comment: thank u but how do I get a subscription? thanks

Comment: @user69492 It's a code on something in the package: A CD box, a manual, etc. You type it somewhere into battle.net and get a confirmation that the code you typed in activated your subscription. Otherwise, a subscription is something you pay for each month. You buy them.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the *World of Warcraft: Battle Chest* includes all of the Expansions, up to and including *Cataclysm*.

With a Starter Edition Subscription you can only go up to level 20, with a gold cap of 10 per character. You can play a Panda, but the Monk class is restricted to the Mists of Pandaria Expansion.

***Note**: You can have up to 11 characters per realm (50 in total across all realms), the same as an active account, but all characters are individually capped at Level 20 and 10 gold. To progress past this point you will need to buy the Battle Chest, which currently comes with a month of free game time.

Cataclysm lets you level up to level 85 with an active account (account that has gametime/subscription), and play all of the content up to and including Cataclysm.

Thus, if you want to explore Pandaria, level past 85, etc., you will have to buy Mists of Pandaria expansion as well.

***Notice**: You do get a month of free game time with the Battle Chest, which changes it from a Starter Edition, meaning you can level up to 85 with it. **IMPORTANT**: Once this is done, you cannot use it as a Starter Edition any more, meaning no free play on lowbie characters - NO EXCEPTIONS.

Also, you can do a 10-day free MoP trial before activating the game time or subscription.

Comment: "You can have as many characters as you want"
Max. 10 per realm and 50 overall.

Comment: @MichaelK Thanks for pointing that out :) Sidenote, the max per realm has been increased to 11 with the introduction of the 11th class (Monk).

Comment: Good to know, I did not play since MoP release.

Comment: @MichaelK Are you coming back for Draenor?

Comment: Not likely. I have played a few weeks during MoP (leveled one new char to max and did a few dungeons) and I just can't get into it anymore.
I pretty much found a new home with Wildstar now.